# Gravação/Edição de Checkbox Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, checkbox, laravel-blade, laravel-5.2

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um Cadastro de Cursos em Laravel 5.2. Criei o CRUD perfeitamente, ele cria, edita e exclui tudo certo, porém nesse cadastro possui 3 itens que são do tipo CHECKBOX, eu consigo registra e salvar no banco (MySQL) corretamente, porém se precisar fazer uma edição no curso, os CHECKBOX estão desmarcados, preciso que eles fiquem selecionados. Alguém poderia me ajudar ou dar uma sugestão de como posso fazer isso ?

**CursosController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Curso;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CursosController extends Controller
{
//Função Principal da Controller
public function index()
{
    return view('cursos.index');
}
//Função para Listagem de Cursos
public function listar()
{
        Session::put('curso_search', Input::has('ok') ? Input::get('search') : (Session::has('curso_search') ? Session::get('curso_search') : ''));
        Session::put('curso_field', Input::has('field') ? Input::get('field') : (Session::has('curso_field') ? Session::get('curso_field') : 'nomeCurso'));
        Session::put('curso_sort', Input::has('sort') ? Input::get('sort') : (Session::has('curso_sort') ? Session::get('curso_sort') : 'asc'));

        $cursos = Curso::where('nomeCurso', 'like', '%' . Session::get('curso_search') . '%')
        ->orderBy(Session::get('curso_field'), 

        Session::get('curso_sort'))->paginate(15);
    return view('cursos.list', ['cursos' => $cursos]);
}
//Função para Criação de Cursos
public function create(){

    return view('cursos.formulario');
}
//Função para Salvar o novo Curso
public function store(Request $request){

    //Instaciamento da model Curso;
    $curso = new Curso();

    //Solicitação de requisições para salvar as informações no BD(Foreign Key)
     $curso->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
     $curso->mantenedora_id = auth()->user()->mantenedora_id;

    //Solicitação de requisições para salvar as informações no BD;
    $area_competencia = implode(", " , $request->get('area_competencia'));
    $curso->area_competencia = $area_competencia;

    $curso->nomeProvincia = $request->get('nomeProvincia');

    $nomeMantenedora = implode(', ', $request->get('nomeMantenedora'));
    $curso->nomeMantenedora = $nomeMantenedora;

    $curso->nomeCurso = $request->get('nomeCurso');
    $curso->formatoCurso = $request->get('formatoCurso');
    $curso->validacao = $request->get('validacao');
    $curso->AvalParticipante = $request->get('AvalParticipante');
    $curso->cargaHoraria = $request->get('cargaHoraria');
    $curso->nivelEstrategico = $request->get('nivelEstrategico');
    $curso->periodicidadeCurso = $request->get('periodicidadeCurso');
    $curso->tpoCurso = $request->get('tpoCurso');
    $curso->nomeResponsavel = $request->get('nomeResponsavel');
    $curso->telefoneResponsavel = $request->get('telefoneResponsavel');
    $curso->emailResponsavel = $request->get('emailResponsavel');
    $curso->desenvolvimentoCurso = $request->get('desenvolvimentoCurso');
    $curso->composicaoCurso = $request->get('composicaoCurso');
    $curso->public_alvo = $request->get('public_alvo');
    $curso->rquestoCurso = $request->get('rquestoCurso');
    $curso->DescricaoCurso = $request->get('DescricaoCurso');
    $curso->OutrasInf = $request->get('OutrasInf');

    //Comando para salvar no BD
    $curso->save();  

    //Fachada da Mensagem de Sucesso 
    Session::flash('msg_sucesso','Curso cadastrado com sucesso!');

    //Retorna para o formulário
    return view('cursos.formulario');

}

//Função para ver o relatório do curso cadastrado de acordo com id;
public function report($idCurso)
{
    $curso = Curso::find($idCurso);

    //Se estiver tudo ok, retorna a view de update;
    return view('cursos.report', compact('curso'));
}

//Função para EDITAR dados do curso cadastrado;
public function edit($id)
{
    //Variável para localizar o ID do Curso.
    $curso = Curso::find($id);
    return view('cursos.formulario', ['curso' => $curso]);
}

public function update($id, Request $request){

    $curso = Curso::findOrFail($id);

    $area_competencia = implode(", " , $request->get('area_competencia'));
    $curso->area_competencia = $area_competencia;

     $curso->nomeProvincia = $request->get('nomeProvincia');
    // $nomeProvincia = implode(', ', $request->get('nomeProvincia'));
    // $curso->nomeProvincia = $nomeProvincia;

    $curso->nomeMantenedora = $request->get('nomeMantenedora');
    // $nomeMantenedora = implode(', ', $request->get('nomeMantenedora'));
    // $curso->nomeMantenedora = $nomeMantenedora;
    $curso->nomeCurso = $request->get('nomeCurso');
    $curso->formatoCurso = $request->get('formatoCurso');
    $curso->validacao = $request->get('validacao');
    $curso->AvalParticipante = $request->get('AvalParticipante');
    $curso->cargaHoraria = $request->get('cargaHoraria');
    $curso->nivelEstrategico = $request->get('nivelEstrategico');
    $curso->periodicidadeCurso = $request->get('periodicidadeCurso');
    $curso->tpoCurso = $request->get('tpoCurso');
    $curso->nomeResponsavel = $request->get('nomeResponsavel');
    $curso->telefoneResponsavel = $request->get('telefoneResponsavel');
    $curso->emailResponsavel = $request->get('emailResponsavel');
    $curso->desenvolvimentoCurso = $request->get('desenvolvimentoCurso');
    $curso->composicaoCurso = $request->get('composicaoCurso');
    $curso->public_alvo = $request->get('public_alvo');
    $curso->rquestoCurso = $request->get('rquestoCurso');
    $curso->DescricaoCurso = $request->get('DescricaoCurso');
    $curso->OutrasInf = $request->get('OutrasInf');

    $curso->save();

    Session::flash('msg_edit_sucesso','Curso atualizado com sucesso!');

    return Redirect::to('cursos/'.$curso->id.'/editarcurso');
}

//Função para Excluir Curso
public function destroy($id)
{
    //Variável para localizar o ID do Curso, se não encontrar retorna erro;
    $curso = Curso::find($id);

    //Variável de deleção do ID;
    $curso->delete($id);

    Session::flash('msg_del_sucesso','Curso excluído com sucesso!');
    return Redirect::to('/cursos');
}   
}
```

model **Curso.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Curso extends Model
 {
 public $fillable = ['nomeCurso','description'];

 public function Provicia(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Provincia::class);
 }

 public function Mantenedora(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Mantenedora::class);
 }
}
```

View **formulario.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('main-content')
@if(Session::has('msg_sucesso'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        {{Session::get('msg_sucesso')}}
    </div>
@endif
<div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-header">
      <h2 class="box-title">Cadastro de Cursos e Atividade Formativas</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="box-body">
        <!-- Abertura do Formulário -->
        @if(Request::is('*/editarcurso'))
        @section('htmlheader_title')
            Editar Curso
        @endsection
        {!! Form::model($curso, ['method' => 'PATCH' , 'url' => 'cursos/'.$curso->id.'editarcurso']) !!}
        @if(Session::has('msg_edit_sucesso'))
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                {{Session::get('msg_edit_sucesso')}}
            </div>
        @endif
        @else
        {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'cursos/salvar')) !!}
            @section('htmlheader_title')
            Novo Curso 
            @endsection
        @endif
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:20px">
            <legend>1 - Dados da Atividade Formativa</legend>
            <!--Campo Nome do Curso-->
            <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:18px">
                {!! Form::label('nomeCurso', '1.1 - Curso / Atividade Formativa*') !!}  <a type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nomeModal" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                {!! Form::input('text', 'nomeCurso', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' =>'required','autofocus', 'placeholder' =>'Digite o nome do Curso/Atividade Formativa']) !!}
            </div>
            <!--Campo Carga Horária-->
            <div class="col-md-6"> 
                {!! Form::label('cargaHoraria', '1.2 - Carga horária') !!} <a type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cargaModal" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                {!! Form::input('int', 'cargaHoraria', null, ['class' => 'form-control' ,'autofocus', 'placeholder' => 'Digite a carga horária em horas.'])  !!} 
                <br>                            
                <!--Campo Validacao --> 
                {!! Form::label('validacao', '1.3 - Validação') !!} <a type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#validacaoModal" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                {!! Form::select('validacao', array('Não há'=>'Não há','Diploma'=>'Diploma', 'Certificado'=>'Certificado', 'Declaração'=>'Declaração', 'Outro documento'=>'Outro documento'), null, [ 'class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus','placeholder' => 'Validação do Curso/Atividade Formativa'])!!}
                <br>
                <!--Campo Avaliação de Participante-->
                {!! Form::label('AvalParticipante', '1.4 - Existe avaliação dos participantes?') !!} 
                {!!Form::select('AvalParticipante', array('Sim'=>'Sim','Não'=>'Não'), null, [ 'class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus','placeholder' => 'Avaliação dos participantes'])!!}
                <br>
                {!! Form::label('periodicidadeCurso', '1.5 - Periodicidade') !!} <a type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#periodicidadeModal" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                {!!Form::select('periodicidadeCurso', array('Mensal'=>'Mensal', 'Bimestral'=>'Bimestral', 'Semestral'=>'Semestral', 'Anual'=>'Anual', 'Bienal'=>'Bienal', 'Trienal'=>'Trienal'), null, [ 'class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus','placeholder' => 'Escolha a periodicidade do Curso/Atividade Formativa'])!!}
                <br>
                {!! Form::label('tpoCurso', '1.6 - Tipo de Curso / Atividade Formativa* ') !!} <a type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tpoModal" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                {!!Form::select('tpoCurso', array('Presencial'=>'Presencial', 'A distância'=>'A distância', 'Ambos'=>'Ambos'), null, [ 'class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus','required' =>'required','placeholder' => 'Escolha o tipo de Curso/Atividade Formativa'])!!}
                <br>
                {!! Form::label('nivelEstrategico', '1.7 - Nível Estratégico') !!}
                <a type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nivelModal" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                {!!Form::select('nivelEstrategico', array('Tático'=>'Tático','Estratégico'=>'Estratégico','Ambos'=>'Ambos'), null, [ 'class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus','placeholder' => 'Escolha o nível estratégico do Curso/Atividade Formativa', 'style' => ''])!!}
                <br>
                {!! Form::label('formatoCurso', '1.8 - Formato') !!}
                <a type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formatoModal" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                {!! Form::select('formatoCurso', array('Curso'=>'Curso','Treinamento'=>'Treinamento','Capacitação'=>'Capacitação','Formação'=>'Formação','Programa'=>'Programa','Retiro'=>'Retiro', 'Treinamento'=>'Treinamento', 'Seminário'=>'Seminário', 'Encontro'=>'Encontro'), null, [ 'class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus','placeholder' => 'Escolha o formato do Curso/Atividade Formativa'])!!}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom:15px">
                {!! Form::label('area_competencia', '1.9 - Área de Competência') !!} <a type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#categoriaModal" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="area_competencia[]" value="Comunicação"> Comunicação<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="area_competencia[]" value="Foco no resultado (na Missão)"> Foco no resultado (na Missão)<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="area_competencia[]" value="Gestão de Pessoas" > Gestão de Pessoas<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="area_competencia[]" value="Identidade Marista"> Identidade Marista<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="area_competencia[]" value="Inovação"> Inovação<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="area_competencia[]" value="Visão Estratégica"> Visão Estratégica<br>
                <br>
                {!! Form::label('nomeProvincia', '1.10 - Curso vinculado a* ') !!} <a type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#provinciaModal" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            <br> 
                 @foreach (App\Provincia::all() as $provincia)
                       <input type="checkbox" value="{{ $provincia->sigla_provincia }}">  {{ $provincia->sigla_provincia }} - {{ $provincia->nomeProvincia }} <br>
                    @endforeach
                <br>
                <br>
                {!! Form::label('nomeMantenedora', '1.11 - Curso vinculado a qual mantenedora?*') !!} <a type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mantModal" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <br>
                @foreach (App\Mantenedora::all() as $mantenedora)
                    <input type="checkbox" name="nomeMantenedora[]" value="{{ $mantenedora->sigla_mantenedora }}">  {{ $mantenedora->sigla_mantenedora }} - {{ $mantenedora->nome_mantenedora }} <br>
                @endforeach
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <legend>2 - Dados do Responsável pela Atividade Formativa</legend>
                <!--Campo Nome da Responsável -->
                <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:15px">
                    {!! Form::label('nomeResponsavel', '2.1 - Nome do Responsável* ') !!} <a type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#provinciaModal" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    {!! Form::input('text', 'nomeResponsavel', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus', 'placeholder' =>'Digite o nome do Responsável pelo Curso / Atividade Formativa', 'required' =>'required']) !!}
                </div>
                <!--Campo Telefone do Responsável -->
                <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom:15px">
                    {!! Form::label('telefoneResponsavel', '2.2 - Telefone do responsável* ') !!} <a type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#provinciaModal" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    {!! Form::input('text', 'telefoneResponsavel', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus', 'placeholder' =>'Digite o telefone do Responsável pelo Curso / Atividade Formativa', 'required' =>'required', 'type' => 'phone' , 'required' =>'required']) !!}
                </div>
                <!--Campo Email do Responsável -->
                <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom:15px">
                    {!! Form::label('emailResponsavel', '2.3 - E-mail do responsável*') !!} <a type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#provinciaModal" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    {!! Form::input('text', 'emailResponsavel', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus', 'placeholder' =>'Digite o email do Responsável pelo Curso / Atividade Formativa' , 'required' =>'required','type'=>'email' ]) !!}
                </div>
                <!--Campo Desenvolvimento do curso -->
                <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom:15px">
                    {!! Form::label('desenvolvimentoCurso', '2.4 - Desenvolvimento do Curso / Atividade Formativa') !!} <a type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#provinciaModal" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <select class="form-control" name="desenvolvimentoCurso" id="desenvolvimentoCurso">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione a modalidade de desenvolvimento</option>
                        <option value="Externo" >Externo</option>
                        <option value="Interno" onchange="alert('teste");">Interno</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <!--Campo composição do curso -->
                <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom:15px">
                    {!! Form::label('composicaoCurso', '2.5 - Composição da Equipe Responsável ') !!} <a type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#provinciaModal" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    {!!Form::select('composicaoCurso', array('Irmãos'=>'Irmãos', 'Leigos'=>'Leigos', 'Ambos'=>'Ambos'), null, [ 'class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus','placeholder' => 'Selecione a composição do Curso / Atividade Formativa'])!!}
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Campo Descrição do Curso  -->
            <legend>3 - Outras Informações</legend> 
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <!--Campo outras informaçoes sobre o curso -->
                        {!! Form::label('rquestoCurso', '3.1 - Pré-requisitos') !!} <a type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#provinciaModal" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        {!! Form::textarea('rquestoCurso', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus', 'placeholder' =>'Caso haja pré-requisitos para o Curso / Atividade Formativa, descreva-os.', 'size' => '30x5']) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <!--Campo outras informaçoes sobre o curso -->
                        {!! Form::label('public_alvo', '3.2 - Público Alvo') !!} <a type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#provinciaModal" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        {!! Form::textarea('public_alvo', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus', 'placeholder' =>'Digite o público que se deseja atingir com o Curso / Atividade Formativa.', 'size' => '30x5']) !!}
                        <br>
                    </div>   
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    {!! Form::label('DescricaoCurso', '3.3 - Descrição do Curso / Atividade Formativa') !!} <a type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#provinciaModal" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    {!! Form::textarea('DescricaoCurso', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus', 'placeholder' =>'Escreva uma breve descrição sobre o curso  e/ ou atividade formativa.', 'size' => '30x5']) !!}
                    <br/>
                    <!--Campo outras informaçoes sobre o curso -->
                    {!! Form::label('OutrasInf', '3.4 - Outras Informações ') !!} <a type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#provinciaModal" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    {!! Form::textarea('OutrasInf', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus', 'placeholder' =>'Digite outras informações que julgue necessárias sobre o curso  e/ ou atividade formativa.', 'size' => '30x5']) !!}
                    <br>
                    <div class="col-md-10" style="margin-bottom:50px">   
                        {!! Form::submit('Salvar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
                        {!! Form::reset('Limpar formulário', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>                
@include('cursos.modals')
@endsection
```

Comment: Tenta adicionar isso no seu `input` alterando a string que vc procura em cada, não tenho certeza se funciona pois não tenho como testar aqui, `{{  strpos($curso->area_competencia, "Comunicação") === false ? "" || "checked='checked'" }}`

Comment: Eu teria que fazer essa alteração na view ?
    <input type="checkbox" name="area_competencia[]" value="Comunicação" {{ strpos($curso->area_competencia, "Comunicação") === false ? "" || "checked='checked'" }} > Comunicação

ficaria assim?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo. Se o `||` não funcionar troca por `:`

Comment: Também não deu certo!

Comment: Mas da algum erro ou só não vem marcado ? Se não está dando erro pode ser algum problema com acentuação, por isso não encontra a string, se não for erro de PHP tenta com uma string sem acento para testar.

Comment: ErrorException in 07517a794f0be852a83aa9b14ac0dd3659f0085a.php line 65:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/html/sig_homologacao/resources/views/cursos/list.blade.php)

Comment: Aparece este erro ai.

Comment: Mas esse erro é no arquivo list.blade.php e o que você mostro o código é do formulario.blade.php, no list.blade.php pelo que eu vi, o nome da variavel é `$cursos` e no formulario é `$curso`, você alterou isso quando usou no list ?

Comment: Não , eu nem tinha percebido isso rsrs. Vou verificar agora